# atalho com alt e duas letras

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

boa tarde
tenho esse codigo aqui

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log(e.which); // Retorna o número código da tecla
  console.log(e.altKey); // Se o alt foi Pressionado retorna true
  if ((e.altKey) && (e.which === 80)) { // Pesquisar (Alt + P)
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Abriu Pesquisa.';
  }
});
```

ele e alt mais a letra mais no caso preciso de duas letra exemplo alt+p+o e possivel
alguem que saiba poderia me ajudar 
desde ja agradeço

Comment: O Alt+Tecla+Tecla não é uma combinação única. O que ocorre nas aplicações desktop é algo como Alt+tecla1 seguido de Alt+tecla2.

Comment: interessante poderia me dar um exemplo, talvez isso possa me ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A captura de teclas pode pegar uma tecla por vez e mais o estado do `shift`, `ctrl` ou `alt`. Então seu código pode capturar a primeira escolha e esperar pela segunda. Na segunda captura, ele executa a ação que você deseja.

Exemplo ilustrativo:

```js
var firstA = false;
var firstB = false;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

  if (e.altKey && e.which === 65) { 
    $(".key-a").css("background-color", "yellow");
    firstA = true;    
  }
  if (e.altKey && e.which === 66) { 
    $(".key-b").css("background-color", "green");
    firstB = true;    
  }
  if (firstA === true && e.altKey && (e.which === 49 || e.which === 97)) {
    $(".key-a-1").css("background-color", "orange");
    firstA = false;
  }
  if (firstA === true && e.altKey && (e.which === 50 || e.which === 98)) {
    $(".key-a-2").css("background-color", "orange");
    firstA = false;
  }
  if (firstB === true && e.altKey && (e.which === 49 || e.which === 97)) {
    $(".key-b-1").css("background-color", "orange");
    firstB = false;
  }
  if (firstB === true && e.altKey && (e.which === 50 || e.which === 98)) {
    $(".key-b-2").css("background-color", "orange");
    firstB = false;
  }
  if (!firstA || !firstB) {
    // limpa tela
    setTimeout(function () { $(".key").css("background-color", "white") }, 2000);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Menu</p>
<ul>
  <li class="key key-a">
    <p>Item 1 (ALT + A)</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="key key-a-1">Item 1.1 (ALT + A + 1)</li>
      <li class="key key-a-2">Item 1.2 (ALT + A + 2)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="key key-b">
    <p>Item 2 (ALT + B)</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="key key-b-1">Item 2.1 (ALT + B + 1)</li>
      <li class="key key-b-2">Item 2.2 (ALT + B + 2)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>
```